# Qt read dynamic qproperties in stylesheets

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

I'm writing an application that contains widgets with different Qt-properties. One of these properties is a simple color-property:

```
Q_PROPERTY(QColor color GET color SET setColor NOTIFY colorChanged)
```

I would like to be able to access this property from within a stylesheet to change how the widget looks.
The stylesheet will be supplied by a user and cannot be dynamically created within the application.
I do not know what the user wants to make the application look like, but I want to give them the opportunity to set colors (and other properties) based on dynamic properties of the widget:

```css
MyWidget {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: <color property value>
}
```

In terms of color, according to the [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#paletterole), the desired behaviour should be possible by accessing the widget's palette:

```css
MyWidget {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: palette(window);
}
```

However, as numerous people have already reported, this doesn't seem to be working as intended, since the stylesheet doesn't access the widget's own palette, but the application palette instead.

As mentioned in the [Qt wiki](https://wiki.qt.io/Dynamic_Properties_and_Stylesheets), one can access dynamic properties by using either a selector for reading, or using `qproperty-` as a prefix for writing.

The stylesheet for **writing** a custom property looks like this:

```css
MyWidget {
  border: 1px solid red;
  qproperty-color: red;
}
```

**Reading** a custom property using a property-selector looks like this:

```css
MyWidget[color="red"] {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

(note: i'm not sure if this selector would actually work, I haven't tried this with colors).
Now this would work for my case if I had a small set of possible colors.
However, my application computes a color dynamically, which would result in 2^24 (not counting alpha) colors.

Seeing that write access to properties can be obtained by using `qproperty-color: <value>;`, i'd have expected read access to be syntactically symmetrical:

```css
MyWidget {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: qproperty-color;
}
```

However, this doesn't work, hence me posting here.

Has anyone found any other way to access properties and using them in stylesheets to change the way widgets look without knowing the possible values beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem around a month back, and I also tried to solve it with `StyleSheet` but ultimately ditched the idea of using `StyleSheet` for `QPalette`.

Using StyleSheet to change the widget's look is a lot of work, especially if the widget is resizable. I would suggest using `QPalette` instead. However, with `QPalette` there is a catch: some styles, especially the default ones like `window` doesn't let you override all the properties of the palette of that style. I would suggest changing the default style of your application to `fusion` and using its palette in your application:

```
#include "mainWindow.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QStyleFactory>
#include "start.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication::setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("Fusion")); // Setting Fusion Style
    QPalette light = QApplication::palette(); // Getting Fusion Style Palette
    Start S(light); // Making Changes to the palette
    QApplication A(argc, argv);
    mainWindow W(&S, &A); // Passing the palette to main window so that you can change it dynamically
    W.show();
    return A.exec();
}
```

Using `fusion` style has many advantages:

- Supports customization of almost all `ColorGroup` and `ColorRole`
- Has a dark theme: [FusionDarkTheme](https://github.com/Jorgen-VikingGod/Qt-Frameless-Window-DarkStyle)
- Easier to maintain than `StyleSheet`

To be able to change the background of your widget you will also have to set it's `autoFillBackground` value to `true` otherwise its parent's background will override the widget's background. It's one of the reasons why you are unable to change the background color of your widget. You don't have to make the change individually for each widget, you can do it like this:

```
void mainWindow::setAutoBackgroundForWidget()
{
    QList<QWidget *> widgets = this->findChildren<QWidget *>();
    for(QWidget *wid : qAsConst(widgets))
    {
        QList<QByteArray> pro = wid->dynamicPropertyNames();
        if(!pro.isEmpty())
        {
            for(QByteArray byt : qAsConst(pro))
            {
                if(byt == "Level")
                {
                    wid->setAutoFillBackground(true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above function `setAutoBackgroundForWidget()` is a function created by me which I call before the end of the constructor of `mainWindow`. This function selects all widget, which has a dynamic property named "Level" to have its own background instead of using its parent's background. You can modify the above function accordingly to select the widgets that you need.

After you are done with the above, all that is left is to use `QColorDialog` to ask your users which color they need, copy the current palette and change the given `ColorRole` in it to the new color and apply the new palette to your widget using `setPalette()`. You can also do it in a single function inside your `mainWindow` cpp file for all your widget.

As for the `StyleSheet`, I can confirm that following works:

```
MyWidget[color="red"] {
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply! Unfortunately, I've tried the setAutoFillBackground trick with no success. 
I'll keep looking for a solution to my issue but it looks like it won't be possible using stylesheets. (and yes, i do need to use stylesheets for my application, because the users want to supply their own looks and be able to change it at runtime, which is not possible with QStyles)...